# prove cardinality rule $|A-B|=|B-A|\rightarrow|A|=|B|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I need to prove this $|A-B|=|B-A|\rightarrow|A|=|B|$
I managed to come up with this:

let $f:A-B\to B-A$ while $f$ is bijective.

then define $g\colon A\to B$ as follows:
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}
  f(x)& x\in (A-B) \\ 
  x& \text{otherwise} \\ 
\end{cases}$$

but I'm not managing to prove this function is surjective.

Is it not? or am I on the right path? if so how do I prove it?

Thanks

Comment: What is the domain of $g$?  What does "otherwise" mean?

Comment: the Domain of g is A otherwise means x does not belong to (A-B)

Comment: Note that the "otherwise" case is precisely the case that $x \in A \cap B$.  Now to show $g$ is surjective, note that for any $y \in B$, either $y \in B - A$ or $y \in A \cap B$.  In each case, find an $x$ with $g(x) = y$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your basic intuition is correct.

First prove that $g$ is injective.

Suppose $x,y\in A$ and $x\neq y$. Let us break this into four cases (two similar):

1. If $x\in B$ and $y\notin B$ (or vice versa) then $g(x)=x$ while $g(y)=f(y)\notin A$, therefore $g(x)\neq g(y)$.
2. If $x,y\in B$ then $f(x)\neq f(y)$ since $f$ is injective, and therefore $g(x)\neq g(y)$.
3. Similarly for $x,y\notin B$, we have that $g(x)=x\neq y=g(y)$.

Therefore $g$ is an injective function.

To show $g$ is surjective, pick $x\in B$.

Either $x\in A$ and therefore $g^{-1}(x)=x$, or $x\notin A$ and therefore $f^{-1}(x)=a$ is defined; $a\in A\setminus B$; and $g(a)=f(a)=x$ as needed.

Comment: You are the best answerer In the world :) Thanks man

Comment: @Jason: You just ask questions I am very familiar with the answers for. Thanks though :-)

Answer (score 8):

Note that

$$\begin{align}
|A| = |A \cap B| + |A \cap B^c| = |B \cap A| + |B \cap A^c| = |B|.
\end{align}$$

Here $E^c$ denotes the compliment of the event $E$ in the universal space $X$.

Comment: I'm not sure this holds for Infinite sets though. And I would prefer and answer that proves there is a bijective function (like my g). But thanks :)

Comment: @Jason, DJC: This solution works for infinite sets as well. For better clarity replace $|A\cap B^c|$ with $|A\setminus B|$ (and similarly with $A^c$), and this will also take care of the case you're working in a setting where no universal set is given (although it is not very hard to produce one).